# tomcat : How to get opened jdbc:oracle connection's stack trace?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, profiling, dump

Have a web application running across multiple locations,
I can see many connections piling up by running this command on linux:

```
ps -ef|grep LOCAL
```

shows me the count of active oracle connections with process id's, and the connection count has been growing up by 5-7 number every hour. After few hours, application slows down and eventually tomcat server needs to be restarted.

As, I am able to see connections growing, Is there any way to  get the source of these connections, to find out what classes or object's have created these laid up connections?

And I am not using Tomcat connection pooling, I tried generating thread dumps by issuing kill -3 tomcat pid, but of no use to me, as I am not able to understand them, even tried thread analyzers.

Is there any simple way to get the originator classes associated with these laid up connections to get a small hint, using some tomcat feature, or by any other means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), you yould use the JDBC probe to get the stack trace that opened a connection. You would select the connection in the timeline

[image]

and jump to the events view

[image]

where you can select the "Connection opened" event. in the lower pane, the associated stack trace is shown.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Comment: Useful but would be better if source code line numbers could be shown. Also I had been running into problems trying to set up JProfiler to connect to a remote instance. Overwriting `JAVA_VM` and/or `JAVA_VENDOR` environment variables (more likely `JAVA_VM`) seemed to cause the problem. Also somehow if JProfiler loses a remote connection, it can become unable to connect to the remote session until it is restarted. But after fixing these problems I was finally able to see the stack trace of connection opens. I wish there was a multi-filter to show both connection open & connection close events.

Comment: In the profiling settings, enable "Record line numbers" on the "Method call recording" tab, then you will see line numbers in the stack traces. As for the multi-filter, I have added this to our issue tracker.

Comment: Quite often the tool just shows "connecting" for a long time. A verbose output of the connection process will be nice to see (in an expandable Details pane) so I can pinpoint what stage the connection process is getting stuck at.

Comment: Usually, if that message is shown for a long time it means that a socket connection cannot be established. Do you actually get a successful connection in your case?

Comment: Yes I get successful connections but not always. Now I can't even get any connection to the JVM from JProfiler any more (even after JProfiler restarts). I have used [Portqry](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/310099) to check that the port is indeed `LISTENING`. It would seem that I need to restart the WebLogic server to get JProfiler to work again. Perhaps the server-side JProfiler library is hung up? I'll try it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for uses of `javax.sql.DataSource.getConnection()` using your IDE.

If you start tomcat in debug mode, you can look for instances of the connection class (and see them increasing). Also, putting a breakpoint on the constructor will catch them in the act of being created.

But really you should be using a connection pool. That is the easiest solution to your problems.

Comment: Not very useful for monster legacy projects with 3000 source files that were worked on by a lot of different people. Sometimes you just want to trace what opened a connection, where and how **without** having to go through the humongous call hierarchy in your IDE (which by the way doesn't even work for JSP).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps these two tools can help you to determine what slows your sever application's performance.

[jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

[ab benchmarking tool](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)

Performance might have slowed due to some simple implementation issues too. You might want to use NIO (buffer oriented, non-blocking IO) instead of IO for web applications, also you might be doing a lot of string concatenations (use StringBuffer).

Comment: Isn't connection pooling not recommended approach to connect to database?

Comment: @artbristol: thanks for the solution.  Actually, the code is on production server, Running application locally by placing breakpoints isn't helping as the situation only comes into picture  when application gets load from various sites. Running tomcat in debug mode on production server would be of any help in finding the root cause of connections?

Comment: @AshishKataria Don't run your production server in debug mode!! (Unless no-one is using it). You need to use one of the tools suggested in this answer to simulate load on a locally-running instance.

Comment: @TemporaryNickName: thanks..i will look upon these tools..
Yeah, doing a lot of string concatenations, how to get over it?

Comment: @artbristol Ok, but as you said.. if using connection pool, Would it still require to analyze?

Comment: @AshishKataria It can't do any harm. It is a very useful skill to learn and will help you on future projects.